# .htaccess Subdirectory Rewrite Exception

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently consolidating posts on a site we recently acquired that had multiple WordPress installs to manage content, one in the `public_html` folder and another in a subdirectory, like so:

```
1. http://domain.com/
2. http://domain.com/another-install/
```

We're moving all of the content from `/another-install/` into the main setup, and using a 301 redirect to remove `/another-install/` from all old links like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/another-install/(.*) http://domain.com/$1
```

Resulting in all articles redirecting like so:

```
http://domain.com/another-install/article-name/
TO
http://domain.com/article-name/
```

The problem is, we want to keep `/another-install/` viewable as a page. With the current redirect, `http://domain.com/another-install/` goes to `http://domain.com/`. Is there any way to add an exception, or rewrite the current rule so that it keeps `/another-install/` viewable?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex from `(.*)` (which matches 0 or more of any character) to `(.+)` (which matches 1 or more of any character). That means there would have to be something following `/another-install/` in order for there to be a redirect.

Comment: Tried this out and cleared out the cache to check. It's now going to `http://domain.com/index.wml` instead of redirecting to the homepage, but it isn't showing a page (I've created one in the main install to show). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `RewriteRule` to specify exclusions. Add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old-install/(index\.wml)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-install/(.+)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```